# Future.get() and executorService.awaitTermination

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

If I use them both the same time (not sure if it's a good habit or not) in following example, what's the actual timeout?

```
ExecutorService executorService = executorServiceFactory.createThreads(2);

List<Callable<T>> tasksList = new ArrayList<>();
tasksList.add(task1);
tasksList.add(task2);

executorService.invokeAll(taskList);

// get the result object with 5 minutes timeout
final task1 = tasksList.get(0).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
final task2 = tasksList.get(1).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

executorService.shutdown();

// set the timeout to 30 seconds for executor service
executorService.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In the above example, I want to get the result of the completable future (used in other places), if I place a 5 minutes timeout in the `get()` method, but I do shutdown the executor service and `awaitTermination` for 30 seconds, which time will take effect? Is it 30 seconds? Since it's shorter than 5 minutes?

Comment: For `tasks.get(0).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` did you really mean `taskList.get(0).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` etc?  If not, what is `tasks`?

Comment: Yeah, I mean `tasksList.get(0).get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` TYPO

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? After ending the await, its possible that task1/2 aren't set to values even though they may have completed and you have waited an indetermined time up to 10m30s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code may wait up to 10 minutes 30 seconds.

It will sequentially wait 3 times.

Code wait for 5 minute for first task, then another 5 minutes for second. So if second task isn't finished in 10 minutes it will wait another 30 second.

If first task finishes within less then 5 minutes it will wait for 5 minutes after first task is complete.

Comment: For task 1 and 2. It either completed within 5 minutes or timeout, correct?

Comment: Not exactly. It wait for 5 minute for first task, then another 5 minutes for second. So if second task isn't finished in 10 minutes it will wait another 30 second.

Comment: What if both tasks take 5 seconds to finish?

Comment: First `get` will take 5 seconds to complete, second one will complete immediately and `shutdown` will also complete immediately.

Comment: If either call to `get` times out, it will throw an exception and `executorService` will not be shut down.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- [Read The Fine Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM), and search Stack Overflow.
- Capture `Future` objects returned by submitting tasks to executor service.
- Use given boilerplate for executor service shut-down.
- Wait until *after* shut-down if you want results after all tasks complete.
- `Future#get` blocks until result is available, or until time-out expires, whichever comes first.

## Details

Your code is not valid Java syntax.

- In `final task1 = …`, you must either declare a return type or use the word `var`.
- In `tasksList.get(0).get`. the first `get` returns a `Callable`. But [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) does not have a `get` method, so your second `.get` fails.

## `List` of `Future` objects

You should be capturing the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects returned by [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
List < Future > futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks ) ;
```

Your shut-down code is incomplete. The Javadoc gives you boilerplate, so use it. Modify this code to use time-outs appropriate to your situation. And I suggest replacing the var name `pool` with `ExecutorService`, as an executor service is not necessarily backed with a thread pool, nor should we really be thinking of an executor service as being merely a thread pool.

```java
 void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Since you want to gather results only after all the tasks complete, you should not be accessing the `Future` objects until *after* this `shutdownAndAwaitTermination` method returns. See the example code in Javadoc for [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface.

For example, if your tasks return a `String` object:

```java
for ( Future < String > future : futures )
{
     try {
       String result = future.get() ;  // Use `Future` object to access its payload, the result of the task’s execution.
       System.out.println( result ) ;  
     } catch ( ExecutionException e ) { … }
}
```

You said:

> I do shutdown the executor service and awaitTermination for 30 seconds, which time will take effect? Is it 30 seconds? Since it's shorter than 5 minutes?

Reading the Javadoc would answer your questions. To quote:

- [`ExecutorService#shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown())
  Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.
- `ExecutorService#awaitTermination`
  Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

## `Future#get` blocks

You asked:

> if I place a 5 minutes timeout in the get() method

Apparently you meant [`Future#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). The Javadoc says:

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.

“Waits” means this line blocks until either result is available or the time-out expires. So whatever code you have below this line is irrelevant.

If you have two calls to `Future#get`, each with a 5-minute timeout, the first call waits up to five minutes, then the second call waits up to five minutes. So the maximum time total is about 10 minutes, while the minimum time is the time taken to immediately return each `Future` object’s payload.

```
String result1 = myFuture1.get( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;  // Blocks up to five minutes. Code below is irrelevant. 
String result2 = myFuture2.get( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ) ;  // Blocks up to five minutes. Code below is irrelevant. 
// At this point, up to 10 minutes may have elapsed maximum (appropriately).
```

I say "approximately" because timing is never exact in conventional Java (as opposed to [real time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java)). Java’s internal scheduling of tasks, and the host OS’ CPU scheduling of the JVM and its threads, means actual elapsed time may vary.

## *Project Loom*

[Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) is work being done on the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project. Its aim is to bring new capabilities to Java’s threading and concurrency facilities.

Among the new features are [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425) and [structured concurrency](https://openjdk.org/jeps/428). These are previewed and incubated (respectively) in Java 19.

These features may generally eliminate the need for [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) which you mentioned but did not discuss. And these may provide a more convenient way to define a set of tasks to be completed together.

For more info, see:

- The JEPs linked above.
- The latest talks and interviews by members of the team such as Ron Pressler and Alan Bateman.
- The talks by José Paumard, [Java Champion](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/new-java-champion-jos%C3%A9-paumard), host of the [*JEP Café*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLX8CzqL3ArzV4BpOzLanxd4bZr46x5e87) channel on YouTube.

---

These topics have been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow. Always search thoroughly before posting. And search now to learn more.